# How can I align page # icons to center?

Tags: html, css

I need help aligning the page # icons (pagination) at the bottom from right to center.

Here is a link to the page:
http://www.vapestore.co/collections/all

Here is the CSS code:

```
.pagination { margin: 15px; padding:10px; border-bottom:1px solid {{ settings.border_and_underline_color }}; border-top:1px solid {{ settings.border_and_underline_color }}; }
.pagination .parts { float:right; }
.pagination .item.dots, .pagination .item.link, .pagination .item.current { display:block; float:left; text-align:center; margin:0 6px 0 0; padding:0; height:20px; line-height:20px; }
.pagination .item.link { color:{{ settings.shop_bg_color_content_area }}; background-color:{{ settings.link_color }}; -webkit-border-radius:3px; width:20px; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Use

```
.pagination .item.link, .pagination .item.current {
    display: inline-block;
}

.pagination .parts {
    text-align: center;
}
```

and remove the floating on both of them.

**Option 2**

Use

```
.pagination .item.link, .pagination .item.current {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 0.25em;
}

.pagination .parts {
    text-align: center;
}
```

and remove the floating on both of them plus width on the first selector.

Comment: First option worked for me, thanks!